# Uncaught Reference Error

Tags: apex, soql, javascript

jScript

```
for (var i = 0; i < {!pLat}.length; i++){  
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng({!pLat}[i], {!pLng}[i]),
            map: map
        });

        info = {!pName}[i]; //line causing error
        marker.setTitle((i + 1).toString());
        setInfo(marker, info);
    };
```

> error Uncaught ReferenceError: Tree6 is not defined

Controller

```
List<Tree2__c> oTree = new List<Tree2__C>();
List<String> name = new List<String>();
public List<String> pName {get;set;}

public conMap(){
  oTree = [SELECT Name, Location__c, Type_of_Tree__c, Action__c FROM Tree2__c];
  for(Integer i=0;i<oTree.size();i++){
  name.add(oTree[i].Name);
}

pName = name;
```

Anyone have any ideas how to solve this?

After some fidling it appears defining Tree6 as a var

```
 var Tree6 = 'Test';
```

This makes it appear as the issue is the contents of the list pName are being viewed as varaibles in the jscript. How do I have it so they are viewed as strings?

Comment: I would assume the pName only has indexes 0-5? You are going on the JS Length of pLength and using that to get the index of pName which may not be the same size as plat? I cannot see where you are populating pLat but pName seems to be from oTree which is a query and may only have 5 records...

Comment: I should have added that all varaible is the prefix p e.g. pLat are being pulled from oTree. The error seems to be that the jScript thinks that the contents of the list e.g. pName[0] is a variable and not a String.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the error is being thrown is as you suspect. The script in the page is trying to use the values from the list/array as variable names. The reason this is happening is because of the way that the array is being rendered into the page markup.

You should leverage the JSON class to serialize the List into an array of strings in a JavaScript-appropriate manner and store those arrays in JavaScript vars. You will need to do the same thing with your arrays of Lat/Long values.

---

For this example, let's assume the `List<String>` in the controller contains three string values: "one", "two" and "three". We'll assign them in the constructor:

**Apex Class**

```
public with sharing MyClass {

    public List<String> pName { get; set; }

    public MyClass() {
        pName = 'one,two,three'.split(',');
    }

    public string getpNameJSON(){
        return JSON.serialize(pName);
    }
}
```

**VF Markup**

```
    <script>
        // an array of strings inappropriate for JavaScript - WITHOUT quotes
        var pNameOutput = {!pName};

        // an array of strings appropriate for JavaScript - WITH quotes
        var pNameJSONOutput = {!pNameJSON};

        // first element of the array, no quotes, interpreted as a variable reference - error
        var pNameOutputArray = {!pName}[0];

        // first element of the array, with quotes, as a string
        var pNameJSONElementZero = {!pNameJSON}[0];

    </script>
```

**As rendered in the browser**

```
<script>
 // an array of strings inappropriate for JavaScript - WITHOUT quotes
 var pNameOutput = [one, two, three];

 // an array of strings appropriate for JavaScript - WITH quotes
 var pNameJSONOutput = ["one","two","three"];

 // first element of the array, no quotes, interpreted as a variable reference - error
 var pNameOutputArray = [one, two, three][0];

 // first element of the array, with quotes, as a string
 var pNameJSONElementZero = ["one","two","three"][0];

</script>
```

**Your code similarly modified:**

```
// store the array of strings in a var
var pNameArray = {!pNameJSON};

for (var i = 0; i < {!pLat}.length; i++){  
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng({!pLat}[i], {!pLng}[i]),
        map: map
    });

    info = pNameArray[i]; // get the item from the array declared above
    marker.setTitle((i + 1).toString());
    setInfo(marker, info);
};
```